# Splitting up an array of supertype into arrays of subtypes

Tags: c#, types

I have the following definitions:

```
class X {
    private ICollection<A> listOfObjects;
}

class A

class B : A 

class C : A
```

Right now I want to split up this list of objects and create separate lists for each type.
I thought the solution I came up with would suffice, but my list never gets populated. Am I overlooking something?

```
foreach (var obj in listOfObjects) {
    if (obj.getType() == typeof(B)) {
         SomeList.Add((B) obj);
    } else if (obj.GetType() == typeof(C)) {
         AnotherList.Add((C) obj);
    }
}
```

Is this the correct approach? I couldn't locate an error elsewhere in my program. The debugger showed me the evaluation actually passed, but the list stays empty.

Comment: Have you tried `listOfObjects.GroupBy(x => x.GetType())` ?

Comment: You say the evaluation passed. Are you using the debugger to observe the contents of the lists immediately before, during, and after the `if` statements?  Perhaps something else is resetting them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
  class X {
      private ICollection<A> listOfObjects;

    public List<B> GetBs() {
      return  listOfObjects.OfType<B>().ToList();
    }
    public List<C> GetCs() {
      return listOfObjects.OfType<C>().ToList();
    }
  }

  class A {}

  class B : A {}

  class C : A {}
```

Comment: I have followed the suggestion provided by both you and Marcin and this worked like a charm, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Using type comparisons with `.GetType()` and/or `typeof()` is generally a bad practice. Instead you should try:

```
foreach (var obj in listOfObjects) {
    if (obj is B) {
         SomeList.Add((B) obj);
    } else if (obj is C) {
         AnotherList.Add((C) obj);
    }
}
```

but you could also skip the `foreach` loop and do this:

```
SomeList.AddRange(listOfObjects.OfType<B>());
AnotherList.AddRange(listOfObjects.OfType<C>());
```

Comment: Out of curiosity `Using type comparisons with .GetType() and/or typeof() is generally a bad practice` Why?

Comment: I was going to ask the same as I4V, could you shed some light on this? I have looked into your solution but received warnings. I've solved the issue by trying out a different approach as suggested by other comments first.

Comment: @I4V Firstly because it is rather hackish. You are retrieving two Type objects and comparing them instead of using a built-in language construct. But more importantly, the `GetType() == typeof()` approach fails to correctly observe class relationships (polymorphism). If you had a fourth class `D` that inherited from `B` and an object `dObj` of type `D`, then `dObj is B` would correctly evaluate to `true`, but `dObj.GetType() == typeof(B)` would evaluate to `false`.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Which of the two approaches I suggested produced warnings (and what were the warnings?). The second approach I proposed is very similar to Marcin and Pieter's and I answered slightly before them.

Comment: What OP want to do is obvious. So does he/she really need this (`But more importantly, the GetType() == typeof() approach fails to correctly observe class relationships (polymorphism)`)

Comment: @I4V No, the polymorphism portion is not relevant in this particular case, but as I said, `GetType() == typeof()` is hackish and a bad practice, and bad practices should be avoided even if they happen to work for a particular case.

Comment: @JLRishe We return to my first comment. `but as I said, GetType() == typeof() is hackish and a bad practice` Why? Just because you say so?  is OP's question not acceptable usage?

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ:

```
var ofB = listOfObjects.OfType<B>().ToList();
var ofC = listOfObjects.OfType<C>().ToList();
var ofA = listOfObjects.Except(ofB).Except(ofC).ToList();
```